# Send an ID from React to Node.js using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to send an id from React to Node.js.

Here is React code:

```
...
 <Button className='button' onClick={() => toggleButton(data)}>click</Button>

...

  const toggleButton = (data) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000/testAPI', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        id: data.id,
      },
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function (body) {
        console.log(body);
      });
  };
```

and here is in Node.js (testAPI.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('req: ', req);
  console.log('res: ', res);
});
```

it prints a lot of data in terminal log but nowhere the information sent from React.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Look in `res.body`, it should contain the data that is sent from front-end

Comment: You're posting to a route called testAPI but that route doesn't exist in your Express app. Maybe try `router.post('/testAPI'...`

Comment: @Andy like `router.post('/testApi', function (req, res) { ...` ?  it returns 404

Comment: Check the spelling of `testAPI`. Note the capitalised letters.

Comment: And then check for `req.params` not just `req` otherwise you'll get a load of junk logged rather than the information you want.

Comment: @Andy, I don't get that. If it's helpful, here is the pushed code: https://github.com/raresmigea/promos . The api file: https://github.com/raresmigea/promos/blob/master/api/routes/testAPI.js, the front-end file: https://github.com/raresmigea/promos/blob/master/client/src/components/Line.js

Comment: @AbhishekGowda28 res.body seem undefined

Comment: @Andy `req.params` is still huge with unuseful data

Answer (score 0):

check the root in your nodejs code. it should '/testAPI'

```
router.post('/testAPI', function (req, res) {
      console.log('req: ', req);
      console.log('res: ', res);
    });
```